# Adding some audio tags with AngularJS: compile error

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am getting a compile error when opening a page containing this code:

```
<p>Audio/Video: 
    <video controls="controls">
    <source data-ng-src="./audio_video/{{myContainer.audioguidefilepath}}">
    </video>
</p>
```

The output of Chrome console is this:

```
 Error: [$interpolate:noconcat] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.9/$interpolate/noconcat?p0=.%2Faudio_video%2F%7B%7Ba.path%7D%7D
    at Error (native)
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.9/angular.min.js:6:416
    at g (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.9/angular.min.js:89:153)
    at Pa (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.9/angular.min.js:68:450)
    at W (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.9/angular.min.js:54:61)
    at S (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.9/angular.min.js:52:102)
    at S (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.9/angular.min.js:52:270)
    at S (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.9/angular.min.js:52:270)
    at S (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.9/angular.min.js:52:270)
    at S (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.9/angular.min.js:52:270) <div data-ng-view="" class="ng-scope">
```

It seems quite a simple code. My controller is just initializing the variable myContainer:

```
if(received) {
            $scope.myContainer = received;
}
```

where received is a JSON object:

```
{
"name": "aName", 
"imagefilepath": ""
}
```

I can see "name" value correctly.

What's wrong with it?

Comment: how is `audio.path` calculated? the error is saying that you are trying to concatenate multiple expressions.

Comment: @Claies it could actually be null. It is a field returned by a REST API and assigned to a $scope variable.

Comment: please show the code that is being used to return the value, since angular is telling you that you have multiple expressions but there is only one visible in the code you posted....

Comment: @Claies I updated the code to include the controller info. Also, I dropped the ng-repeat, as I am now returning just a string, not a list of strings referring to the video file paths.

Comment: so when the JSON object has data in it, the data is a full path value? no expressions?

Comment: I've just made a test with this value: "aaa" and I get the same error, regardless of it being null or "aaa". If I remove the source line, no error appears.

Comment: take a look at this and see if it helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22468526/angular-interpolatenonconcat-error-in-directive

Comment: Great, no compile error. However, the file is not being loaded, even though the path seems to be correct.

Comment: When I use iframe it works correctly, though, but I cannot sto autoplay!